# Use resources from external dependent jar

Tags: gradle

I have a jar which contains the infrastructure for a certain feature and one of the common resources it embeds if `logback.xml`.

How can a different build which depends on this one (dependent jars not on local file system) extract the `logback.xml` file, modify it and store it as part of its own distribution?

I presume I need to add the dependency in the `buildscript` but where do I go from there?

Answer (score 0):

**This seems to work:**

```
distributions {
  main {
    contents {
      into ("log") { 
        from zipTree(configurations.runtime.filter { it.name.startsWith('myjarname') }.singleFile)    
        include "logback.xml"
      }
    }
  }
}
```